# Jupyter Bokeh and large list filter with suggestions?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, bokeh

As a Jupyter newbie I am experimenting with Bokeh graphs, but I've hit a problem with the use of filters.

I want to provide a dimensional filter on one field, but that fields has over 30,000 different values (think 'customer' name).

Is there a bokeh filter that can provide...

- A drop down selector that responds to user text character input (e.g.
  typing in the characters 'Jam' to see a list of the customers that
  start with those characters) A selector that supports multi item
  selection

Answer (score 0):

[Panel](https://panel.pyviz.org) provides a Bokeh-based widget like that:

```
import holoviews as hv, panel as pn, panel.widgets as pnw
hv.extension()

pnw.CrossSelector(options=list(range(30000)), value=[3, 967])
```

[image: screenshot]

It does initialize the list with all of the options, and for 30,000 entries it takes a few seconds to start up and isn't as snappy interactively as one might like. But it's usable...